# php - deleting only checked files AND folders

Tags: php

First time around,hope to get some help:

I am trying to create a `delete.php` script that starts with the confirmation "button" and deletes only the selected /trought the checkbox/ files AND/or FOLDERS(including the files within)

this is my code so far:

```
<style>
td, th {border:2px solid gray; padding:2 30px;}
</style>
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file: <input type="file" name="imeNaFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Filename</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Delete:</th>
</tr>

<?php 
$path = ".";
$dh = dir($path);
while( ($file=$dh->read()) ) 
{
   if( $file=="." || $file=="..")continue;
   echo "<tr><td><a href='download.php?f=$file' title='Click to Open/Download'>$file</a></td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo (is_file($file))? " F ": " D ";
   echo "</td><td>" .filesize($file)."</td>";
   echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'/></td>";
}
?>
</table>
<form method="post" action="delete.php" ecntype="multipart/form-data">
Please confirm if you wish to delete the selected files 
<input type="button" value="Detele selected files" onclick="return confirm('DELETE the selected?');" />
</form>
`
```

Comment: And where is a question?

Comment: the question - what to put into the delete.php in order to get FILES or FOLDERS , deleted if checked? no matter if it is a file, or a fodler- containing other files.